# Fill PIL ImageDraw Line partially

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to fill a line by a different color increasingly like a progress bar. This is the image:

[image]

It was created with this code

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

image = Image.new("RGBA", (300, 300), color="black")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
width = 7
image_w, image_h = image.size
coord_a = image_w / 2, width
coord_b = width, image_h / 2
coord_c = image_w / 2, image_h - width
coord_d = image_w - width, image_h / 2
draw.line([coord_a, coord_b, coord_c, coord_d, coord_a], fill="red", width=width, joint="curve")
image.show()
image.save("test.png")
```

I'm trying to fill it with different color like this:
[image]
Should I just fill each line separately and combine them all?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question! You could have lots of fun thinking up ways to do this.

---

1. As you suggest, you could draw the rhombus as four separate lines. You would have to calculate the point where the red and blue portion met using sin/cos but that's not too hard.

---

2. You could draw it much more simply as the four sides of a square with its sides initially horizontal and vertical, then rotate it 45 degrees into place when you are finished drawing. I think I would go for this option.

---

3. You could draw a single long horizontal red line, and then overdraw the correct percentage in blue. Then cut it into four pieces, rotate and paste onto the black square background.

---

4. You could get the coordinates of all the points on the rhombus using scikit-image `draw.polygon_perimeter()` as documented [here](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.draw.html#skimage.draw.polygon_perimeter). Then colour the first however many percent blue and the remainder in red. You could make the lines thicker using morphological dilation.